# Get the value of the cell to the right in VBA

Tags: excel, cell, vba

What is the simplest code to get the value of the cell to the right of the current one?

`Selection.Worksheet.Cells(Selection.Row, Selection.Column + 1).Value` is a bit verbose.

Comment: Whoever voted to close, can you please explain?

Comment: These cowards never dare to step forward. Ruining the site anonymously is something that shouldn't be posible; All votes should be identifiable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The shortest code seems to be:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(, 1).Value
```

Reference: [ActiveCell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221612(v=office.11).aspx), [Offset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060(v=office.15).aspx). Both parameters to `Offset` are optional, and the `RowOffset` is omitted.

Comment: And what if we want a range-of-cell's right cell?